# git upload-pack cannot download packfile

Tags: git

```
#git upload-pack --stateless-rpc --advertise-refs data/build-your-own-x
010d8e628eb428a55ea4909de4af9a82e99db346ed83 HEADmulti_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow deepen-since deepen-not deepen-relative no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed no-done symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master object-format=sha1 agent=git/2.34.1
003f8e628eb428a55ea4909de4af9a82e99db346ed83 refs/heads/master
00468e628eb428a55ea4909de4af9a82e99db346ed83 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
00488e628eb428a55ea4909de4af9a82e99db346ed83 refs/remotes/origin/master
```

```
#git upload-pack --stateless-rpc data/build-your-own-x/
0032want 8e628eb428a55ea4909de4af9a82e99db346ed83
0000
```

**After run the above command, get nothing, no error, no packfile.**

In [git doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols), it says:

> ```
> => POST $GIT_URL/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.0
> 0032want 0a53e9ddeaddad63ad106860237bbf53411d11a7 
> 0032have 441b40d833fdfa93eb2908e52742248faf0ee993 
> 0000
> ```
>
> Again, this is the same format as above. The response to this request indicates success or failure, and includes the packfile.

But I cannot get packfile either by request like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the protocol](https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-protocol/2.2.3) you would also need to indicate the end of the request using

```
0009done
```

`0000` seems to indicate the end of the `want` list, not the end of the request. Only when the end of the request has been read the packfile will be sent back.